# Firefox: Cross-domain requests with credentials return empty

Tags: firefox, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

Firefox [send a cross-domain post with credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054316/jquery-sending-credentials-with-cross-domain-posts), I can (using Charles - a proxy for HTTP debugging) see that the server is sending back the response… But Firefox isn't "letting me see it" (for lack of a better description).

For example, using [the documented example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control#Requests_with_credentials):

```
>>> var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
>>> invocation.open('GET', 'http://localhost/~wolever/cookie.php', true);
>>> invocation.withCredentials=true;
>>> invocation.onreadystatechange = console.log;
>>> invocation.send()
http://img.skitch.com/20100113-bq3a4qb1ufn52331x18ce3c7xu.png
>>> invocation.responseText
""
>>> invocation.responseXML
null
```

However, Charles tells me that this request has, in fact, returned the expected response:

http://img.skitch.com/20100113-njakyu4xequ5e3cyfhfnyeatq5.png

Any idea what could be going wrong?

And, incase it helps: the same request without credentials returns data as it should.

Comment: Just a wild guess, can you try replacing `localhost` by `127.0.0.1` in case some "special case" magic happens when using localhost?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is from the bottom of the MDC section you linked to:

> Important note: when responding to a credentialed request,  server must 
>   specify a domain, and cannot use wild carding.  The above example would fail
>   if the header was wildcarded as: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.

I bet you missed this, it's hidden under a couple big example code blocks.