# same-origin-policy conflicting with basic authentication?

Tags: jquery, ajax, authentication, same-origin-policy

After configuring the webservice-server to support CORS by adding 
`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` 
to the apache virtual host conf, a new problem occured.
I call the webservice using jquery 1.5:

```
$.ajax( {
    type: "GET",
    url: wsBaseUrl + "?action=xyz",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(data){
        wsCallback(data);
    }
});
```

This one works cross-domain with the adapted server config. However if the webservice needs authentication, which is the case on production system, it breaks again.

For authentication I add the jquery ajax params

```
    username: "userx",
    password: "passx",
```

Authentication alone (not cross-domain) works. But as soon as it's combined (authentication + cross-domain), it's over. jQuery invokes the error-callback telling me that the request is not allowed. I logged the requests with TamperData in Firefox and no webservice request is logged there. It may however be that a so called preflight is not logged there (but if so, why does that depend on authentication?). 
I tried all combinations on my test-system and I'm quite sure that's the correct conclusion.
Now I'm really stuck. What else can I do to debug / work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control#Requests_with_credentials), simple `GET` requests are NOT preflighted but in the case of credentialed requests (like when you add the username, password in your example), the server MUST respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` in order for FF 1.5+ to allow the request to complete.

**Update**

See also [Sending credentials with cross-domain posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054316/jquery-sending-credentials-with-cross-domain-posts)

Comment: I think that's the right hint! Now I'm trying to find out how to add that to the response header for code 401.

Comment: The strange stuff continues. After adding this header, the ajax request fails with "401 (Authorization Required)". I'm sure authentication is correct as - again - w/o cross-domain invocation it works (I can easily check that by having different domains pointing to the same test server)

Comment: I vote this answer as matching. It misses some things also required to solve this, but it brought me on the right track. Also check "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054316/jquery-sending-credentials-with-cross-domain-posts" for this issue.

Comment: Glad to hear you've got it figured out and thanks for the heads up, I've added the link to that answer in my answer as well.