# Cross site Ajax.Request with cookies and Prototype.js

Tags: prototypejs, cross-site

I need to tell `Ajax.Request` (from `Prototype.js`) to set `xhr.transport.withCredentials` to `true` (to enable cookies in my cross site requests headers). I failed by trying:

```
Ajax.Request('http://otherSubdomain.host:port/', {
    onCreate: function(request){
        request.transport.withCredentials = true;
    }
});
```

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is set and the `request` is successful, but **no cookies were sent**.

I hate to point out, but it seems to be much easier with `jquery`
here is an <kbd>**[example solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054316/jquery-sending-credentials-with-cross-domain-posts)**</kbd>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to patch `Ajax.Request` like this:

```
Ajax.Request.prototype.request = Ajax.Request.prototype.request.wrap(function(request, url) {
  if (this.options.withCredentials) {
    this.transport.withCredentials = true;
  }
  request(url);
});
```

And then you'll have additional option `withCredentials`:

```
new Ajax.Request('example.com', {
    withCredentials: true
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this error occurs: SyntaxError: super is a reserved identifier.

Comment: OK, replace `super` with something else (I've edited my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Improved Victor's answer a bit.

Fixes in IE where it requires setting withCredentials between 'open'    and 'send' and makes it consistent with jQuery ajax options.

```
Ajax.Request.prototype.setRequestHeaders = Ajax.Request.prototype.setRequestHeaders.wrap(function(setHeaders) {
  setHeaders();
  if (this.options.xhrFields) Object.extend(this.transport, this.options.xhrFields);
});
```

And then to use it:

```
new Ajax.Request('example.com', {
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  }
});
```