# Browsers send Origin header on ajax requests, but not with simple HTTP Get request. Why?

Tags: ajax, http, cookies, cross-domain, cors

I'm using SignalR as my push server (.NET stuff), and somewhere in the process, the script sends an ajax request, but doesn't send the cookies.

However, when I open that request in a new tab, all of the cookies are sent alongside.

Notes:

1. `X-Requested-With` is not defined (the code is `$.ajax()`, but seems that browser considers this request as a cross-domain request)
2. Push server is running on `domain.com:7171`
3. App server is running on `domain.com`
4. The URL works with `GET` method
5. When we send a simple request to the same URL from the address bar (simple HTTP Get), cookies are sent

Why cookies are sent to the same URL when it's an HTTP get request, and are not sent when it's an ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that this is a cross-domain request from domain.com to domain.com:7171. Cookies are not included by default on cross-domain requests. You need to explicitly indicate that you want to include cookies by setting `.withCredentials = true;` [in your JQuery request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054316/jquery-sending-credentials-with-cross-domain-posts). Your server will also need to respond with the header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`. You can learn more here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/