# My CSS cant load web font woff files located on an other https+auth server (CORS related)

Tags: cors, webfonts

My CSS is hosted on https://www.site1.com (it is an authenticated domain) and it uses `woff/ttf` files located on https://media.site1.com (it is also authenticated - same auth than www). To connect to these sites, I must use an authenticated proxy.

I have to enable CORS to allow cross domain loading, but it seems that I can't load resources from another domain if this domain is basic-authenticated AND I use an authenticated proxy.

I have added in Apache the following directives:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.*)$" origin_is=$0 
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
```

It should allow all Origin, but when the CSS loads the `woff` file (via GET request), I get:

**Request**  (only interesting headers) :

```
GET file.woff HTTP/1.1
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Host  media.site1.com
Origin  https://www.site1.com
Proxy-Authorization Basic XXX1234567
Connection  keep-alive
Cache-Control   max-age=0
```

**Response** (as seen by Firebug or Httpfox) :

```
HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate    BASIC realm="Unspecified"
Server  BigIP
Connection  close
Content-Length  0
```

If I manually authenticate to `media.site1.com` before going to www, the result is the same. It seems that the browser does not send basic-auth credentials to the "media" server.

Are there any additional headers I have to set to ensure that WOFF files are loaded from a different location, with basic-authentication and eventually with an enterprise authenticated proxy?

Answer (score 9):

We just ran into the same situation.

According to the W3C spec, fonts linked from CSS files must be loaded in "anonymous" mode: https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-css-fonts-3-20131003/#font-fetching-requirements
So basically the browser will normally never send the authentication cookies.

The way I understand it, you have 2 options:

1. Disable authentication for font files on https://media.site1.com
2. This is a hack and I'm not entirely sure it will work. You can try to issue an AJAX request to load the font before the CSS file, as described here: https://css-tricks.com/preventing-the-performance-hit-from-custom-fonts/ Of course, in this article they are doing it for performance reasons, but nevertheless, the idea is to load the font file seperately, so that when the CSS file is loaded the browser will get it from its cache. You may need to add the `withCredentials` header in your AJAX call, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7190487 Also, given that usually you load CSS files at the top of your page and JavaScript at the bottom, to prevent the CSS file from loading first and issuing the failed requests you will need to load it dynamically on the success callback of the AJAX call.

I know the 2nd solution seems like too much trouble, but I couldn't come up with a better one.

Comment: Why was this limit introduced only with web fonts? why not with css, js etc..?

Comment: @elad.chen I can only guess that the authors of the W3C spec intended fonts to be easily and freely loadable from other servers, which in a way makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [AsGoodAsItGets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38263198/117259)’s answer, I was able to better understand a server config issue I was dealing with; everything was working well on a CAS authenticated server… But the fonts were consistently not being loaded as expected with other local assets.

While I appreciate [AsGoodAsItGets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38263198/117259)’s answer, it did not provide a bare-bone practical example of how to to adjust a web server config on an authorized directory to allow fonts to pass trough, I decided to post this answer showing how to do it. It’s fairly simple; the override happens in the `<FilesMatch>` config stuff:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">

  <IfModule mod_auth_cas.c>
    AuthType        CAS
    CASAuthNHeader  On
    Require valid-user
  </IfModule>

  <FilesMatch "\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$">
    AuthType None
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    Satisfy Any
  </FilesMatch>

</Directory>
```

That  config basically says, “If CAS is enabled use it and only allow CAS authenticated user’s through… But if a file extensions matches the common font extensions out there — `.eot`, `.svg`, `.ttf`, `.woff` and `.woff2` — just let it pass without any authentication.”

Set that, restarted Apache and suddenly all the fonts appeared as expected and no errors in my browser’s inspector console.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Giacomo1968 :) In my defense, we were not using Apache to serve the files, we were using a Java/Weblogic server, so I'm afraid your solution wouldn't have worked for us, that's why I proposed those 2 options in my answer. But I'm sure some people will find your answer helpful!