# Play Framework 2.5 - How to share cookies in distinct domains

Tags: ajax, cookies, playframework

I'm facing some issues while trying to work with cookie in distincts domains. In my scenario I have two apps (**app1** and **app2**). Basically, the **app1** is doing an *ajax request* to the **app2** in order to this one creates a cookie (i.e. dummyCookie). The **app2** is an application running over the [Play framework 2.5 for Java](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaHome). I'm creating the cookie like this:

```
response().setCookie(Http.Cookie.builder("dummyCookie", "9e0a6b4c-58ed-b700-0000-015ec494956").build());
```

I'm using the plays's **CORSFilter**:

```
package myCustomFilters.filters;

import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter;
import play.http.DefaultHttpFilters;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Filters extends DefaultHttpFilters {

    @Inject
    public Filters(CORSFilter corsFilter) {
        super(corsFilter);
    }
}
```

In my **application.conf** I have this configuration:

```
play.http.filters = "myCustomFilters.Filters"

play.filters {
  cors {
    pathPrefixes = ["/"]
    allowedOrigins = null
    allowedHttpMethods = ["POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"]
  }
}
```

In the **Chrome's console**, in the **Network** tab, I could see the cookie in the response header.

[image]

If I check the **Application** tab, **Cookies session,** I couldn't see the cookie there:

[image]

I did some investigations and maybe the problem is related to the scenario "**CORS + AJAX**", since that I have one application calling (via ajax request) the another one to generate a cookie.

Guys, somebody already faced with this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues. I had to tweak the configuration in different ways to make that work in Chrome. And client request also need some specific changes (I use JQuery, and this kind of approach was necessary : [Sending credentials with cross-domain posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054316/sending-credentials-with-cross-domain-posts)).

However, in the end, I discovered that Safari would most likely never work for me, as Apple now has [specific rules](https://webkit.org/blog/7675/intelligent-tracking-prevention/) to handle when cookies can be sent cross domain or not. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, this might lead you to consider a totally different approach.